# Not able to edit lookup field with multiple selection in quick edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, quick-edit, multi-select

Lookup fields with multiple selection becomes grayed while creating a new record using quick edit mode.

Once the record exist, using the quick edit, there is no problem for modifying lookup fields with multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on SharePoint online?

I can reproduce your issue in SharePoint online modern experience.

Lookup fields with multiple selection works fine while creating a new record using quick edit mode in classic experience.